# Strange Null Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, runtime-error, nullreferenceexception

Getting a strange Null Object Reference Error from calling "sliderValue.Content = widthValue" as defined below inside of the slider's ValueChanged event handler.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StrangeError.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="166.066" Width="326.351">
<Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="widthSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" TickFrequency="10" SmallChange="0.01" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Ticks="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10" ValueChanged="widthSlider_ValueChanged" Minimum="1"/>

    <Label x:Name="sliderValue" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace StrangeError
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int widthValue;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        widthValue = 1;
        sliderValue.Content = 1;
    }

    private void widthSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        widthValue = (int)widthSlider.Value;
        sliderValue.Content = widthValue;
    }
}
}
```

Error (raised from calling sliderValue.Content = widthValue):

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code (...)
```

However, everything works perfectly fine if I move that statement into another eventhandler. It only raises this error when I call it from the ValueChanged event, which is strange.

Comment: have you attached to see what is null?

Comment: Well are `sliderValue` and `widthSlider` both non-null?

Comment: Yes. I updated the original question with the initialization bit.

Comment: it's really "Strange Null Object Reference Error".

Comment: You should post more of your code because i have a feeling you are doing some other weird stuff. Maybe you are calling the `sliderValue.Content` before your UI has been Loaded.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the full source code. Throw it into Visual Studio and give it a run -- you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Perhaps while initializing it already triggers the value changed event, before initializing the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you posted, it seems `sliderValue` is somehow null.
I'm not sure how exactly that can happen, given that you use it in your constructor...
Anyways, this example is perfect for you to use WPF bindings:

```
<Slider x:Name="WidthSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" TickFrequency="10" SmallChange="0.01" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Ticks="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10" Minimum="1" />
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=WidthSlider, Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, I found out what your problem is:
When `InitializeComponent()` is called, the value of `widthSlider` changes.
This triggers your `widthSlider_ValueChanged` event, but because `widthSlider` is initialized before `sliderValue`, `sliderValue` will be `null` at this point.

So basically, just add:

```
if(sliderValue != null)
{
    ...
}
```

to your event and everything should be fine.

I've noticed this before with WPF and events like these. They will **really** tell you what changes when.

PS: you really should mention that the exception happens before the application starts in cases like these. It can save some time.

Comment: I know I could easily use data binding to take care of this -- but I'm more inclined to find out why exactly this produces a Null Object Reference Error, for the sake of learning, as I've never had this error come up before in any other case.

Comment: I'd say put breakpoints in your constructor method, look at the values there, put breakpoints in the change event and maybe look at the output panel, it will sometimes tell you things about WPF mix ups.

Comment: Ahh -- makes sense. I didn't realize I was unintentionally raising that event before things finished initializing.

Comment: Nice answer. To avoid this *if* everytime the value is changed, I set the event after the `InitializeComponent()` call in `MainPage()` method. Thanks, this helped me :)